# Is there a vocabulary for linking weather data?

Tags: data-request, weather, linked-data, ontology, json

I've got a weather station and want to publish the data in [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/).

For the context file I'm searching for a vocubulary to express the weather data. 
Is there already a vocabulary or 'setup' for this kind of data?

Comment: not sure about specifically LD, but look into setting up  your weather station on WeatherUnderground - http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/about.asp

Comment: The station is already on Weatherunderground :)

Comment: related: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5895/protocol-software-to-publish-weather-information-online?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We (met.no) plan on publishing a JSON-LD vocabulary for climate/weather data, when we release our public portal later this year. We'll be publishing JSON-LD ourselves as our primary data format.

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't anything else stable out there yet suitable for this kind of use. The closest you get, AFAIK, is http://codes.wmo.int/

Comment: Perfect! Finally a governmental organization taking the lead in this :) Do you need some beta-testers for creating feeds in the new format ;)

Comment: Well, first we need to get something published. :-)

Comment: You can follow development on Github (https://github.com/metno). We do (almost) all of our development as open-source, and publish everything to Github (we're also big on open data: http://om.yr.no/verdata/free-weather-data/). The project to keep an eye on is met-api (https://github.com/metno/met-api), which we intend to build as our new (JSON-LD based) data API platform. It currently only contains throwaway prototype code, but - funding allowing - we should start rolling out the first bits and pieces of the API (and supporting schemas/metadata) later this year.

Answer (score 6):

The two links below are NOAA/NWS weather terms used in their datasets:

This document is the vocabulary for the annual summaries:

http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cdo/documentation/ANNUAL_documentation.pdf

This document is the vocabulary for the daily summaries
http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cdo/documentation/GHCND_documentation.pdf

These are a subset of the NOAA codes for the most common weather terms:

TMIN - min daily temperature
TMAX = max daily temperature
PRCP = daily percipitation in mm
AWND = average daily wind speed in km/hrs
SNOW = Snowfall in mm
SNWD = Snow depth in mm
ASCH = Average cloudiness (percent)
TSUN = Total daily sunshine (minutes)
WTxx = Weather Type
•01 = Fog, ice fog, or freezing fog
•02 = Heavy fog or heaving freezing fog
•03 = Thunder
•04 = Ice pellets, sleet, snow pellets, or small hail
•05 = Hail
•06 = Glaze or rime
•07 = Dust, volcanic ash, blowing dust, blowing sand, or blowing obstruction
•08 = Smoke or haze
•09 = Blowing or drifting snow
•10 = Tornado, waterspout, or funnel cloud
•11 = High or damaging winds
•12 = Blowing spray
•13 = Mist
•14 = Drizzle
•15 = Freezing drizzle
•16 = Rain
•17 = Freezing rain
•18 = Snow, snow pellets, snow grains, or ice crystals
•19 = Unknown source of precipitation
•21 = Ground fog
•22 = Ice fog or freezing fog

Answer (score 5):

The common vocabulary for weather data is the Weather Exchange Model (WXXM). Read more here: https://wiki.ucar.edu/display/NNEWD/WXXM

Answer (score 2):

Meteo is out there: http://purl.org/ns/meteo.   I have no idea how well-used it is.